# regex substitution no global modifiers available

Tags: regex

I'm using software with built-in regex implementation that does not support global modifiers, so I have to get it working without /g

my test string is(number of sections can be unlimited:

aaa%2dbbb%2dccc%2dddd%2deee

I want it to be: aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd-eee

normally I would write (%2d) and g flag and substitute with -

I managed to write this to match unlimited number of occurrences

(\w)((%2d)(\w+))+

but I have problems with substitution rule, because my group 2 has 2 subgroups and I cannot find out how to handle them,

can anyone help with substitution rule?

Comment: where are you trying to use this? because normally (for example in editors) there might not be global modifiers but you can still just `replace all`

Comment: its application that has its own built-in stupid regex with no global modifiers

Comment: it's also poorly documented so i can try to type replace all in some guessed ways thanks for advice

Comment: replace all does not help too(tried in front, after regex)

Comment: Which software are you using?

Comment: it's not regex software its customized closed software provided directly to us, but with built-in regex(seems based on c++ regex lib) that usually was enough good :) for application

Comment: You could try to use an inline modifier: `(?g)%2d`

Comment: did not work with inline too, thanks for advise anyway, at least tried something that forgot to check :)

Comment: @k-five this software limits to apply it loop; I apply this rule on live data and after 1st iteration forward them further; so need to correct in one go without global flag.

Comment: It's interesting - when its too difficult to answer - question is down-voted. would be nice to here reasons for it. Till today I have helped many people dealing with regex, even here on SO; but when there is a problem that puts me back in seat telling - learn more regex, guys who cannot help can just down-vote it.

Comment: Thanks to commenters that tried!!! Just did not work too (tested all advices)

Comment: Even an editor as crude as notepad on windows can use replace-all. So what do you exactly mean by "replace all does not help too"? You click replace all and nothing happened or it give you some error tips?

Comment: This problem can't be solved with regular expression in one go. If capture group is used with quantifier such as `+`, the content of the capture group will always be the last match found. In your case, the content of the 2nd capture group will be %2deee, and you can't get %2dbbb, %2dccc and so on, so there is chance for you to substitute it.

Comment: Regular expression can't solve your problem. You have to try to bypass the limitations of the software by yourself, unless you tell us which software you are using.

Comment: @ltux thx that's how I thought; I'm trying to intercept those files and rename with python before app gets them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As comments in the end reach same conclusions that I had before posting question, I decided to post answer to close the question nicely (instead of deleting question, cause even negative answer is answer and may save someone an hour or more on research(that happened to me actually)). The general conclusion is - it's not possible to solve this with regex. And I'm quoting two best comments by @ltux here:

> This problem can't be solved with regular expression in one go. If capture group is used with quantifier such as +, the content of the capture group will always be the last match found. In your case, the content of the 2nd capture group will be %2deee, and you can't get %2dbbb, %2dccc and so on, so there is chance for you to substitute it. – ltux 2 days ago
>
> Regular expression can't solve your problem. You have to try to bypass the limitations of the software by yourself, unless you tell us which software you are using. – ltux 2 days ago

Comment: Can't you use something like `urldecode`, with your string, it replace `%2d` with a dash `-`?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file containing the line type that you want to process:

```
cat << EOF >> abcde.txt
aaa%2dbbb%2dccc%2dddd%2deee
EOF
```

Use this sed snippet as follows using the global substitution you mention as being the way you usually perform such a substitution.

```
sed -e "s#%2d#-#g" abcde.txt
aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd-eee
```

Basically you don't have to think about the type of characters that appear around the white space character but instead only concentrate on the white space itself. Replacing this character multiple times will solve the issue for you quite simply. In other words, pattern matching around the character  you are concerned with changing is not necessary. This is a common issue that many of us fall into when dealing with regular expressions.

Basically the substitution is saying: find the first occurrence of a white space '%2d', replace it with a hyphen '-' and repeat for the rest of the string.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: if you read my last comment on the original question - this is what I try do now - intercept that file before app and rename it, but is not easy to intercept; if I get that file I know 1000 ways to rename it; but thanks for trying to help anyway. same answer to @Toto

Comment: This still uses global modifiers